# Mock custom method to angular unit test jasmine

Tags: angular, firebase, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have mock the router with `getCurrentNavigation` like the following way,

```
const mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
    getCurrentNavigation: () => {
      return {
        extras: {
          state: {
            selectedGamedata: tournamentData,
            joined: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And `tournamentData` is just a const object like

const tournamentData = {
...,
expiry_date,
}

and added this to the provider list of the spec file

```
providers: [
    DatePipe,
    { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
    ...
  ]
```

Then there is a line in my component that is

```
let formatedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.selectedGamedata.expiry_date.toDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss');
```

and Error showing

> Failed: this.selectedGamedata.expiry_date.toDate is not a function

Now I think I should mock this `toDate` function but now I don't know.
Made try with `spyOn` but giving an error

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const tournamentData = { ..., expiry_date, }
```

To:

```
const tournamentData = { ..., expiry_date: { toDate: () => 'Your value here' } }
```

Your TypeScript code expects `expiry_date` to have a `toDate` method on it.

Comment: Solve at **  expect(component).toBeTruthy();  **  but when calling ngAfterViewInit or ionViewWillEnter then it again giving same error.

Comment: That's strange, it shouldn't give the same error. I assume `this.selectedGamedata` comes from `getCurrentNavigation` and you have `expiry_date: { toDate: ...` set on this at the `providers: [...` level.

Comment: Yes I don't know what's went wrong I just noticed If I any of function then even this error thrown.  Find it here If want to see https://tmpfiles.org/dl/96662/contest-start.zip

Comment: One more approach is there when somehow ```selectedGamedata``` not found then I am making an API to fetch the data so ```toDate()``` method not exist there.

Comment: I did same where I fetching data from API call. It worked. thanks.